# How to do a non-blocking read on a non-socket fd

Tags: unix, pipe, nonblocking, file-descriptor, tty

Is there a way to do a *single* `read()` in non-blocking mode on a pipe/terminal/etc, the way I can do it on a socket with `recv(MSG_DONTWAIT)`?

The reason I need that is because I cannot find any guarantee that a `read()` on a file-descriptor returned as ready for reading by `select()` or `poll()` will *not* block.

I know can make the file descriptor non-blocking with `fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK)` but this will change the mode on that file descriptor globally, not just in the calling thread/process. For example:

```
% perl -MFcntl=F_SETFL,F_GETFL,O_NONBLOCK -e 'fcntl STDIN, F_SETFL, fcntl(STDIN, F_GETFL, 0) | O_NONBLOCK; select undef, undef, undef, undef'
^Z # put it in the background
% cat
cat: -: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This will also make the fd non blocking for *both* reading and writing, which may confuse the hell out of another process doing the opposite on the same fd, as in:

```
non_blocking_read | filter | blocking_write
```

One way I think of is to save the file status flags on starting up and `SIGCONT`, and restore them on exiting and on `SIGTSTP` (just the way it's done with the termios settings), but this is very limited, race-prone, and will leave a mess behind in the case where the program exited abnormally.

Putting a save/restore with `fcntl()` before/after each `read()` also feels ugly and dumb, and may have other issues too. The same with an `ioctl(FIONREAD)` just before the `read` (which I'm not even sure it will work reliably with any fd; assurances in that direction will be welcome, though).

I would be happy even with system specific (eg. linux or bsd-only) solutions.

For reference, [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/8/14/135) is a discussion about fixing it in linux; the idea didn't seem to get anywhere, though.

Answer (score 0):

A Linux only solution would be to reopen the file descriptor via
    *"/dev/stdin"|"/dev/tty"|"/dev/fd/$fd"*.

C example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int fd;
    char buf[8];
    int flags;
    if(0>(fd=open("/dev/stdin", O_RDONLY))) return 1;
    if(0>(flags = fcntl(fd,F_GETFL))) return 1;
    if(0>(flags = fcntl(fd,F_SETFL,flags|O_NONBLOCK))) return 1;
    sleep(3);
    puts("reading");
    ssize_t nr = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
    printf("read=%zd\n", nr);
    return 0;
}
```

Unlike a `dup`licated file descriptor, a reopened filedescriptor will have independent file status flags.

Comment: Thanks, that looked promising, but the `open()` will fail with permission denied if the fd was passed down from a process running as another user; example: `su - other_user -c 'cat /dev/stdin'` => `... Permission denied` (the same with your program, if you change the 1st `return 1` to `err(1, "open")`. And it's the same thing with `/proc/self/fd/FD`, pipes, etc.

Comment: That sucks. IMO, it's ugly and dumb that the kernel won't let you use recv with any file as long as you're not passing socket-specific flags. Might as well do the next ugly and dumb thing and save and restore. You could also catch exiting signals to make sure the restoration happens even with e.g., SIGTERM or SIGABRT.