# Duplicating file descriptor and seeking through both of them independently

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

I have an open file descriptor which I want to duplicate in order to perform reading and seeking through both of them independently. I looked at the

```
int dup(int old_fd)
```

syscall. The problem is it does not really fit here. Man page states the following 
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html :

> After a successful return, the old and new file descriptors
>   may be used interchangeably.  They refer to the same 
>   open file description (see open(2)) and thus share file 
>   offset and file status flags; for example, if the file offset is 
>   modified by using lseek(2) on one of the file descriptors, 
>   the offset is also changed for the other.

Is there a way to duplicate a file descriptor so they are completely independent?

Comment: `pread()` and `pwrite()` can be used at positions of your choice. But you have to keep track of it outside of the OS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Linux, opening `/proc/<pid>/fd/<n>` opens the file that's currently open at fd *N*, but this is a new copy, not a linked duplicate like the one you get with `dup()` and friends.

This should create a file that contains `bar`, a bunch of zero bytes, then `foo`. Contrast with the version using `dup()`.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd1, fd2;
    char buffer[50];

    fd1 = open("testfile", O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 0600);
    sprintf(buffer, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd1);
#ifndef USE_DUP
    fd2 = open(buffer, O_RDWR);
    if (fd2 == -1) {
        perror("open");
    }
#else
    fd2 = dup(fd1);
#endif
    if (lseek(fd1, 16, SEEK_SET) == -1) {
        perror("lseek");
    }
    if (write(fd1, "foo", 3) == -1) {
        perror("write(fd1)");
    }
    if (write(fd2, "bar", 3) == -1) {
        perror("write(fd2)");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, very interesting. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @SomeName, I'm not sure. The [`proc(5)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) documents the /proc/<pid>/fd directory, but it only really says that `readlink()` on them gives useful information, and that you can open them (`/dev/stdin` points to `/proc/self/fd/0` in particular, so opening must work). I don't know if any official documentation describes that they're different from `dup()`. Though they must be in that you can open a file from _another_ process's /proc/<pid>/fd.

Comment: Anyway, as long as Linux developers don't seriously change their stance on not messing up with behavior visible to user-space, I don't think the current behavior is going to change.

Comment: But will the symlink become dangling if we move the original file?

Comment: @SomeName, actually, no, it follows renames. Opening it accesses the _inode_ directly, however, the name shown in the symlink is just for show. They're not normal symlinks. (if you have hard links, it can show `(deleted)` in the symlink, even though the file still exists, and you can still open it through the symlink)

Comment: Opening `/proc/self/fd/FD` is still subject to the permissions from the inode, so this is **not a reliable way** to deep dup a fd -- a fd could be opened by a privileged process and passed down via inheritance or `SCM_RIGHTS` to another, less privileged process. The same problem applies when trying to set the non-blocking flag on a per-process or per-call basis. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53673808/how-to-do-a-non-blocking-read-on-a-non-socket-fd), especially the link to the lkml [discussion](https://lkml.org/lkml/2007/8/14/135).

Answer (score 3):

No — at least, not in POSIX-defined mechanisms.

If you want complete independence of the file descriptors, you need to avoid the shared open file description, which means an independent [`open()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html) or equivalent.

There's a chance that there's a Linux-specific mechanism that does the job that I've not heard of.  However, looking through the system calls for Linux at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ didn't provide enlightenment.

Comment: Using `/proc/<pid>/fd/NN` should work.  That does involve a second `open()`, as I stipulated.  The `/proc` file system isn't available on all other o/s.

Comment: The question is about moving files within the same filesystem from one thread of the application and opening `/proc/pid/fd/NN` from another. Will the symlink points to the same file or this will introduce a race condition?

Comment: I'm not sure what scenario you're asking about.  Moving files normally involves the `rename()` function — or maybe `link()` and `unlink()`.  If the file is open, then it can be read even if renamed while it is open (or even if the permissions on the file change).  So probably there isn't a problem — but I'm not sure I know what the context is so that's more of a guess than I'd like it to be.

Comment: If we have a symlink to a file and it is renamed thr symlink becomes dangling symlink then. So I think the kernel takes care of "relinking" `/proc/pid/fd/NN` links in case of such renaming. Is that correct?

Comment: Essentially, the entry in `/proc/<pid>/fd/NN` is up to date at all times.  It's possible that immediately after thread 1 has read the entry for fd 5 (say) and before it can use it in any other system call, thread 2 has changed what fd 5 points at, but that's essentially unavoidable.

Comment: Just check it myself and it worked, but that was somewhat contradictory to the definition of symbolic link that is a pointer to a file via its path. Anyway I tried to find it in the `proc.5` manual but there was no any description that the symlinks under `/proc/pid/fd/NN` are never dangling.

Comment: The entries in `/prod/<pid>/fd/NN` are not the same as the regular symlinks you or I create in a directory.  It's on the special `/proc` file system, and it essentially provides file-system style access to information in the per-process in-kernel memory – everything is a 'pseudo-file' or 'pseudo-directory' rather than a regular file or directory as found on a regular 'disk backed' file system (where 'disk backed' is increasingly a misnomer since it is more like SSD or memory backed).

Comment: @SomeName The visual aspect of the symlink in `/proc/<pid>/fd` might be fake, if the file backing the file descriptor has no name in the file system any more (i.e. deleted). An `open()` call still opens that file. Note that the file name mentioned in the symlink e.g. `/tmp/#4849919 (deleted)` is a valid file name though, but unrelated.